# Javascript change last child label content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I Have this in html it is a BigCommerce Website and their support don't know how to change a name on a varieble. the only thing is that we have to do it with a javascript function:

```html
<dd class="GiftCertificateThemeList" style="display: ">
    <div class="FloatLeft">
    <label>
    <div class="radio">
    <span class="checked">
    <input class="themeCheck" type="radio" value="Birthday.html" name="certificate_theme">
    </span>
    </div>
        Birthday
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
    <div class="radio">
    <span>
    <input class="themeCheck" type="radio" value="Celebration.html" name="certificate_theme">
</span>
</div>
Celebration
</label>
<br>
<label>
<div class="radio">
<span>
<input class="themeCheck" type="radio" value="Christmas.html" name="certificate_theme">
</span>
</div>
Christmas
</label>
<br>
<label>
<div class="radio">
<span>
<input class="themeCheck" type="radio" value="General.html" name="certificate_theme">
</span>
</div>
General
</label>
<br>
<label>
<div class="radio">
<span>
<input class="themeCheck" type="radio" value="Girl.html" name="certificate_theme">
</span>
</div>
Girl
</label>
<br>
<label>
<div class="radio">Valentine</div>
Boy
</label>
<br>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</dd>
```

I need to change the label text of the last item which is boy to Valentine.

Can someone help me to do this ?

I can add javascript no problem.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You aren't closing your divs.

Comment: this is the url: http://www.doubletakeshapewear.com/giftcertificates.php i was just putting the section i want to change.

Comment: You can't have `<div>` inside `<label>`. But when I look at the source on your real web site, you don't have that. Why have you put that here?

Comment: I had a problem copying and pasting. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.radio:last').parent().html(function(){
        var html = $(this).find('div');
        $(this).text('Valentine').prepend(html);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: didn't work. it puts the valentine instead of the radio...

Comment: When I tested it changed the input radio and put the text valentine. I want to change the text boy. I'm testing using firebug on my website: http://www.doubletakeshapewear.com/giftcertificates.php

Comment: There's no `<input>` in the code you posted here. It's not fair to post different code than what you're actually asking about -- the details matter.

Comment: Agree with Barmer, the code is different, I'll update my answer